# how to plot a tree graph in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make a tree like graph in gnuplot, so far I have points with labels arranged into the tree like structure. I would like to connect nodes (points), so each node will be connected to the node on higher level.

```
gnuplot code:
set term png

set output "tree.png"
set xrange [0:50]
set yrange [0:50]



plot 'data.txt' using 1:2:3 with points  pointtype 7 lt 1 title 'title', \
     '' using 1:2:3 with labels offset 0,char 1

data:

20 35 1 
15 30 1.1
10 25 1.1.1
5 20 1.1.1.1
15 20 1.1.1.2

25 30 1.2
30 25 1.2.1
25 20 1.2.1.1
35 20 1.2.1.2
```

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will most likely require to process the input data file externally in order to generate the list of edges on-the-fly.

If I understood your question correctly, each node (point) in your input is associated with a "tree-path" which is just a string of dot-separated integers expressing the position of the point on each level of the graph (tree). Now, two nodes A and B should be connected iff the path of B is longer than path A by 1 (1 extra level) and the path of A is a prefix of path of B (A is parent of B).

To do this, one could assume that the points on the input are already hierarchically ordered as in your example (i.e., that the coordinates of a parent are defined before any of its children) and proceed as follows:

```
set term png

set output "tree.png"
set xrange [0:50]
set yrange [0:50]

fName = 'data.txt'

parseEdges = sprintf('< gawk '' \
    NF==3{ \
        coords = $1 " " $2; \
        data[$3] = coords; \
        n = split($3, path, "."); \
        if(n == 1) next; \
        prefix=path[1]; \
        for(i=2;i<n;i++){ prefix = prefix "." path[i] } \
        if(prefix in data){ \
            print data[prefix] "\n" coords "\n"; \
        } \
    } \
'' %s', fName);

plot \
    fName using 1:2:3 with points  pointtype 7 lt 1 title 'title', \
    '' using 1:2:3 with labels offset 0,char 1, \
    parseEdges w l
```

Here, the gawk script splits the path specification in the third column, extracts its prefix (by stripping the least significant part of the path) and finally checks if the coordinates for this prefix (path of the parent) are already available and if yes, it prints a block of coordinates which is then shown as the connecting edge in the final output. The result is then:

[image]